# Minimum size for door to be obligated in mezuzah

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, mezuzah, architecture-design, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, what is the minimum width and/or height for a door to obligated in a mezuzah? Is it any door, or does it have to be a specific size? And if it has to be a minimum size, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum height is 10 handbreaths. (Rambam Mezuza 6:1)

The Talmud in a number of places (eg. Eruvin 11b) sounds like the minimum width is 4 handbreaths, but Rambam doesn't record that requirement. There's lots of discussion about why (see, eg. Arukh Hashulchan YD 287:9) but probably in the very rare case of a narrower door one should omit the blessing out of doubt.